# read in all csv files with different columns, bind them by row, keep all columns

Tags: r, bind, rows

I want to read in all csv files in my working directory and bind them by row. 
These data frames have different number of columns, I want to keep all columns.

I tried

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv.gz")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))

library(dplyr)
DF<-bind_rows(temp,.id = NULL)
```

Error: Argument 1 must have names

Comment: Can you make up some examples that reproduce this? Because the default of `dplyr::bind_rows` is that column names don't have to match. This error implies that you have objects that don't have names or maybe aren't data frames, not that the names don't match. I'm guessing you're having an issue because `list.files` returns a character vector, so I don't know that you'll get anything useful trying to add the results of `read.csv` to it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the rbind.fill from the plyr package .You could do the following:

```
library(plyr)
data<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
      dat <- read.csv(temp[i])
      data <- rbind.fill(data,dat)
}
```

Comment: Just want to note that `plyr` has been retired in favor of `dplyr` and other tidyverse packages for a couple years now

Answer (score 0):

We can read all the datasets in a `list` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
map_dfr(temp, read_csv)
```